# Python selenium script fails to click on some links

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to initiate click on some links available in a webpage. They are all very similar to hperlinks. The links I wanna click on are the name of each container, as in the first link connected to this name is `Kimpton Muse Hotel` (the name may vary in your case) and so on. I've already examined that my script can parse those names but can't click on those links connected to each name.

***[The webpage link](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=motels+in+new+jersey&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=1&rlla=0&rlhsc=CiEIjc2myO-zjdfsAQjm4uekqp_1vYMBCJ2lpoWkg62PtwEwAQ&rllag=39956030,-74419977,66425&tbm=lcl&ved=2ahUKEwi48eTj-MncAhVG4YUKHXUPA0QQjGp6BAgGEFY&hotel_dates=2018-08-12,2018-08-13&tbs=lf_hd:-1,lf_ho:2,lrf:!1m4!1u13!2m2!13m1!1b1!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e4!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e9!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e8!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e10!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e2!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e3!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e7!2m1!1e13!2m7!1e17!4m2!17m1!1e3!4m2!17m1!1e8!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e4!2m22!1e10!4m2!11m1!1e4!4m2!11m1!1e9!4m2!11m1!1e8!4m2!11m1!1e10!4m2!11m1!1e2!4m2!11m1!1e3!4m2!11m1!1e7!2m21!1e7!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u20000!3sPKR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u30000!3sPKR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u40000!3sPKR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u50000!3sPKR!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:6&rldoc=1#rlfi=hd:2018-08-12,2018-08-13;si:;mv:!1m3!1d946339.8611287393!2d-74.7837865!3d40.2277793!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i146!2i233!4f13.1;tbs:lf_hd:-1,lf_ho:2,lrf:!1m4!1u13!2m2!13m1!1b1!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e4!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e9!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e8!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e10!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e2!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e3!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e7!2m21!1e7!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u20000!3sPKR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u30000!3sPKR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u40000!3sPKR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u50000!3sPKR!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e4!2m1!1e13!2m22!1e10!4m2!11m1!1e4!4m2!11m1!1e9!4m2!11m1!1e8!4m2!11m1!1e10!4m2!11m1!1e2!4m2!11m1!1e3!4m2!11m1!1e7!2m7!1e17!4m2!17m1!1e3!4m2!17m1!1e8!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:6)***

This is my try so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "replace with the link above"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".VkpGBb .dbg0pd div"))):
    # item.click()  #it throws an error when uncommented
    print(item.text)  #this works great
driver.quit()
```

This is the error I get when uncomment the line `item.click()`:

```
line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <div>...</div> is not clickable at point (106, 238). Other element would receive the click: <div jstcache="360" jsaction="cal_select_day:jsl._" class="gws-travel-calendar__calendar">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86)
```

> What I wish to do is click on those links cyclically and that's it.

***The following image shows the links I wish to click on (marked by pencil marker)***

[image]

Comment: Do these links appear within an iframe or something?

Comment: Nope. They are not @SuperStew .

Comment: The calendar widget which is currently hidden overlaps the area where you're trying to click. I'm not sure the right way to handle that _yet_, but that's what's causing your error. Go ahead and expand the calendar widget manually and you can see the area it's overlapping.

Comment: Did you try to click on `<a class="C8TUKc iVV2dCH7jxU0-6WH35iSZ2V0 rllt__link a-no-hover-decoration"` element instead of `<div`?

Comment: It seems you are close @Kiril S. Your solution works only when I kick out `calendar widget`. However, it is still incomplete approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to close Details modal popup on each iteration:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.CngMb g-raised-button.bZEQvc"))).click()
for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".VkpGBb .dbg0pd div"))):
    item.click()
    name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.xpdopen div.SPZz6b span")))
    print(name.text)
    close = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "QU77pf")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", close)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one calendar windows opens up , once we visit the search page.You can click on the **Finish button** and run the same piece of code :

Here how I have done it :

```
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=motels+in+new+jersey&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=1&rlla=0&rlhsc=CiEIjc2myO-zjdfsAQjm4uekqp_1vYMBCJ2lpoWkg62PtwEwAQ&rllag=39956030,-74419977,66425&tbm=lcl&ved=2ahUKEwi48eTj-MncAhVG4YUKHXUPA0QQjGp6BAgGEFY&hotel_dates=2018-08-12,2018-08-13&tbs=lf_hd:-1,lf_ho:2,lrf:!1m4!1u13!2m2!13m1!1b1!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e4!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e9!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e8!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e10!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e2!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e3!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e7!2m1!1e13!2m7!1e17!4m2!17m1!1e3!4m2!17m1!1e8!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e4!2m22!1e10!4m2!11m1!1e4!4m2!11m1!1e9!4m2!11m1!1e8!4m2!11m1!1e10!4m2!11m1!1e2!4m2!11m1!1e3!4m2!11m1!1e7!2m21!1e7!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u20000!3sPKR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u30000!3sPKR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u40000!3sPKR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u50000!3sPKR!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:6&rldoc=1#rlfi=hd:2018-08-12,2018-08-13;si:;mv:!1m3!1d946339.8611287393!2d-74.7837865!3d40.2277793!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i146!2i233!4f13.1;tbs:lf_hd:-1,lf_ho:2,lrf:!1m4!1u13!2m2!13m1!1b1!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e4!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e9!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e8!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e10!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e2!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e3!1m4!1u10!2m2!11m1!1e7!2m21!1e7!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u20000!3sPKR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u30000!3sPKR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u40000!3sPKR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u50000!3sPKR!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e4!2m1!1e13!2m22!1e10!4m2!11m1!1e4!4m2!11m1!1e9!4m2!11m1!1e8!4m2!11m1!1e10!4m2!11m1!1e2!4m2!11m1!1e3!4m2!11m1!1e7!2m7!1e17!4m2!17m1!1e3!4m2!17m1!1e8!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:6") 

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Finished']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".VkpGBb .dbg0pd div")))

for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".VkpGBb .dbg0pd div"))):
 item.click()  #it throws an error when uncommented
 print(item.text)  #this works great
```

Imports would be :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Here is the console output :

```
WestHouse Hotel New York
Kimpton Muse Hotel
Motel 6 East Brunswick
Motel 6 Piscataway
Baymont by Wyndham Atlantic City Madison Hotel
Super 8 by Wyndham Mahwah
Super 8 by Wyndham Mount Laurel
SuperLodge Atlantic City/Absecon
Knights Inn Mount Laurel
Empire Inn & Suites - Atlantic City/Absecon
Horizon Inn
Super 8 by Wyndham Pennsville/Wilmington
Anchor Motel
Knights Inn South Amboy/Garden State Parkway South Exit 125
Studio 6 East Brunswick - NYC Area
Super 8 by Wyndham North Bergen NJ/NYC Area
Hudson Plaza Motel
Motel 6 Elizabeth - Newark Liberty International Airport
Motel 6 Philadelphia Pa - Brooklawn NJ
Travelodge by Wyndham Absecon Atlantic City
Motel 6 New Brunswick NJ
Travelodge by Wyndham Parsippany
```

**Update 1 :**

Wrap the **Finished button** clicking in `try-catch` :

```
try:  
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Finished']"))).click()

except:
   pass
```

Comment: It didn't work. Script thows `timeout exception` error upon hitting the line where you've defined `xpath`.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace : It is working fine at my end though.

Comment: Did calendar open in your system ? I have shared the console output also , note that I am printing after clicking on each link.

Comment: Check this out: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\demo.py", line 33, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Finished']"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: Did calendar open in your system ?

Comment: Yep. It was clearly visible and spread over throughout the time.

Comment: updated the answer under **update1 section** , I have bind that in try-except , hope that will work at your end too.